# ¿Por que tengo error al implementar un anuncio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Veran, quiero implementar un intersticialAd en una de mis aplicaciones, ya logre implementar un banner y todo bien.
Ocurre que ahora para el intersticial, sigo de igual forma lo que esta en la publicacion pero me marca un error, error que Android Studio me ayuda a solverlo pero solo renombrando el metodo llamado.
Indague en internet de esto, pero a todos les sale bien y no tienen mayor problema.
NOTA: El sdk ya esta importado en gradle.

Aqui el codigo:

```
private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

 MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

El error aparece en:

-" InterstitialAd(this)" Error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class

-"mInterstitialAd.adUnitId" Error: val cannot be reassigned

-"mInterstitialAd.loadAd" Error: unresolved reference: loadAd

Reiterando que Android Studio solo me dice: "Rename reference"

Answer (score 0):

Esa era la antigua implementación. A partir de la versión 20, la API cambió para ofrecer un diseño similar a los otros tipos de anuncios a pantalla completa.

Este es el ejemplo más básico posible:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
val adCallback = object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
  override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {}
  override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
    interstitialAd.show(this@Activity)
  }
}
InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, adCallback)
```

Para una mejor implementación lee la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#kotlin). Pero asegurate de seleccionar el idioma inglés porque la versión en español está desactualizada.

Comment: Pero es evidente que como tal si siguió la documentación; ya que exclama que lo ha seguido con un video tutorial de YouTube y ese mismo tuto salía de la Documentación. También tuve un error similar

Comment: @DanielRosas lo siento, parece que soy el único que lee la documentación en inglés. Resulta la guía en español está desactualizada. Edité la respuesta para aclararlo